# Disable algorithm numbers for only certain algorithms in a document

Tags: numbering, algorithms, algorithmic

I have the following MWE

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{BLAH}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\REQUIRE $Input$
\ENSURE $A$.
\STATE Set $A$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{}
\floatname{algorithm}{Not an algorithm but want the layout}
\caption{BLEH} 
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\REQUIRE $Input$
\STATE Compute $B$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{BLAH}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\REQUIRE $Input$
\STATE Compute $B$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

which produces this [image: this] where the third entity is titled Algorithm 3 but I want it to be titled Algorithm 2. How do I achieve this?

**EDIT** I don't want to use any other algorithm environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step down the counter:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\newcommand{\altcaption}[1]{%
  \addtocounter{algorithm}{-1}%
  \renewcommand\thealgorithm{\unskip}%
  \floatname{algorithm}{#1}%
  \caption
}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{BLAH}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\REQUIRE $Input$
\ENSURE $A$.
\STATE Set $A$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\altcaption{Not an algorithm but want the layout}{BLEH} 
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\REQUIRE $Input$
\STATE Compute $B$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{BLAH}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\REQUIRE $Input$
\STATE Compute $B$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @User525412790 I made a small change to remove the added space.

Comment: What's the change? I don't see anything different.

Comment: @User525412790 `\renewcommand\thealgorithm{\unskip}`

Comment: Oh I guess I saw the modified version directly.